# string to array of single characters WITHOUT converting to a list along the way

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to convert a Python string into a NumPy character array where each individual character is its own array element, WITHOUT first converting the string to a list?  I have a program which must do this with a lot of data and I have identified the conversion step itself as a bottleneck, but I cannot seem to find any NumPy function that can directly take a string and convert it in this manner without first creating a generic Python list.

Comment: I want a numpy array of individual characters in order to perform vectorized comparisons between long strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, can use [`fromiter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) specifying dtype to be `unicode` of length `1`.

```
>>> np.fromiter('abcdefg', (np.unicode,1))
```

---

As in [official docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.html),

> The chararray class exists for backwards compatibility with Numarray,
>   it is not recommended for new development. **Starting from numpy 1.4, if
>   one needs arrays of strings, it is recommended to use arrays of dtype
>   object_, string_ or unicode_**, and use the free functions in the
>   numpy.char module for fast vectorized string operations.

So, if you need to use methods like `isalpha()`, use `np.char` module, such as follows, and not `np.chararray` class anymore:

```
>>> np.char.isalpha(x)
```

Comment: You have no idea how many answers I've tried posting until you've been the one to beat me to it.

Comment: Just tested and this seems very close to what I want, but the array must be a chararray so that I can use methods like a.isalpha() on it.  Is there a simple way to do that?  I assume there must be.

Comment: @RafaelC Nope that didn't work, it is still an ndarray after that.

Comment: @Stata oh Ok, I understand your question. I will edit why you don't want that

Comment: `np.array('abcdefg').view((np.unicode,1))` works too

Comment: How to do the opposite, i.e. `array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], dtype='<U1')` back to `'abcdefg'`?

Comment: @Julio if you have an array of strings, you may just join them with `''.join(arr)` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
for i in np.fromstring('ab', dtype='|S1', sep=''):
    print(i.isalpha())
```

OR

```
np.fromiter('abcdefg', (np.str,1))
```

Comment: But then I have to iterate to run isalpha rather than using the chararray vectorized method, which would slow things down.

Comment: `np.fromstring('ab', dtype='|S1', sep='')` would return an ndarray which you can use to perform your vectorized operation.

Comment: Right, that would work as well, now that I realize I can get the vectorized behavior I want without a chararray.  Thanks!